# How to let the seekbar slide automatically/sync to the CountDownTimer as the timer decreases too

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, seekbar

I tried to combine seekBar and CountDownTimer in which I slide the seekBar to a 5 seconds and then release,it will then hit the CountDownTimer code to count from 5 second to 0 second. My problem is as soon as i release the seekBar slide,I want the slide also decreases (move to the left)(automatically) sync with both the timer and the slide reach 0. Help me thank you!!

```
    package com.example.timerrr;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CountDownTimer mCount;
    SeekBar seekbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seekbar= (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTimer);

        seekbar.setMax(60000);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);


        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Log.i("countdown to: ", Integer.toString(progress/1000));

                mCount = new CountDownTimer(progress, 1000 ){

                    public void onTick(long x){
                        Log.i("Countdown",Long.toString(x/1000));
                    }

                    public void onFinish(){
                        Log.i("Countdown","Finish");
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                mCount.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="162dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="428dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="162dp"
        android:onClick="startButton11"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarTimer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.i("countdown to: ", Integer.toString(progress/1000));
            if(!fromUser)
              return;
            mCount = new CountDownTimer(progress, 1000 ){

                public void onTick(long x){
                    Log.i("Countdown",Long.toString(x/1000));
                    seekBar.setProgress((int) x);
                }

                public void onFinish(){
                    Log.i("Countdown","Finish");
                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if(mCount != null)
               mCount.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if(mCount != null)
               mCount.start();
        }
    });
```